# Make adapter more efficient

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I tried to make a custom Adapter and I made it functionall maybe not the best way and may be not the intelligentes Way so I ask here what I can do to make this a little more efficient

```
public class MovieDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements FetchImage.AsyncResponse {
    private Context mContext;

    public MovieDataAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() { // get coutn Method
        SQLiteDatabase db = new MvDBHelper(mContext).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.query(MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cur.getCount();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }//Not needed at the moment

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }// Not needed at the moment

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ImageView imageview;

        if (convertView != null) {
            imageview = (ImageView) convertView; //if used view just use ist again
        } else {//if new view set the fitting parameters
            imageview = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(getw('w'), getw('h')));
            imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        }
        SQLiteDatabase picturedb = new MvDBHelper(mContext).getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cur = picturedb.query(MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null, null, null, null, null, null
        );//get the entries from the db


        if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {

            cur.moveToPosition(position); // move to the appropriate position
            //defining nessesary Variables
            int index_PosterPath = cur.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_POSTERPATH);
            int index_FilePath = cur.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_FILE);
            int index_ortTitel = cur.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_ORTITEL);
            final String Filename = cur.getString(index_ortTitel) + ".jpg";
            final String selection = MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_ORTITEL + " = ?";
            final String[] where = {cur.getString(index_ortTitel)};

            picturedb.close();// db not needed so is closed

            if (cur.isNull(index_FilePath)) {//if file not already saved in the storage save it there

                FetchImage getImage = new FetchImage(mContext, new FetchImage.AsyncResponse() {

                    @Override
                    public void processfinished(Bitmap output) { // get the image as an Bitmap in asynchronus task throug interface callback
                        FileOutputStream fos = null;
                        try {
                            fos = mContext.openFileOutput(Filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            if (fos != null)
                                output.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos); //put bitmap in file
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            if (fos != null) {
                                try {
                                    fos.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_FILE, Filename);
                            SQLiteDatabase picwr = new MvDBHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
                            int updated = picwr.update(MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, where);
                            //put the filname in the db for later use
                            picwr.close();

                        }
                        BitmapDrawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), output);
                        Drawable gridimag = draw;
                        imageview.setImageDrawable(gridimag); // set the drawable as an image
                    }
                });

                String[] ptg = {cur.getString(index_PosterPath)};
                getImage.execute(ptg);
            } else { // if pic already saved in the internal storage get it from there
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = mContext.openFileInput(Filename);
                    Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                    BitmapDrawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), pic);
                    Drawable gridimag = draw;
                    imageview.setImageDrawable(gridimag);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        fis.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }


            cur.close();
        }


        return imageview;
    }

    public int getw(char c) {

        int DisplayWidth = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

        if (c == 'w') {
            return (int) (DisplayWidth / 2);
        } else {
            return DisplayWidth;
        }
    }

    public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
        return px;
    }

    @Override
    public void processfinished(Bitmap output) {

    }
}
```

Would be happy about every help I can get even if it's a complet new Way because at the moment the grid view does not work fluently

Comment: calling `query`  inside `getCount` is not exactly a good idea

Comment: why dont you use `android.widget.CursorAdapter`? there is a simple "out-if-the-box" implementation: `android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid close cursor each time you draw a cell. You can close it only when you done with your activity.

Also you need to avoid using cur.moveToFirst(). Because you are already moving your cursor to given position, why should i moving it first before?

Another trick to use a image loader library (Picasso is one of the best) to load it async and faster. It also handles to stop threads if view is not shown. More optimized.

You dont need to find indexs of coloumn each time you want a new cell. Find them once, use them everytime :)

Also you can use CursorAdapter class to implement it way better :)

Comment: you mean put cursor in the constructor ?

Comment: Yep you can calculate them in constructor.